# is there a faster way to log in with OpenID?

Tags: feature-request, support, openid, login

Ok I admit I'm being greedy. OpenID is working fine for me via WordPress. (For the record, I did read other questions and answers about login and OpenID, but didn't find the answer.)

But could the process contain fewer steps (either by my doing something differently, or by a change to SO)?

From memory, I think this is what I do now:

1. click login
2. click WordPress icon
3. type my WordPress username
4. click OK
5. It takes me to WordPress with a very long URL and tells me to log in to WordPress
6. I highlight the part of the URL that's extra, replace it with the word "login"
7. It doesn't delete the part I tried to delete, so I highlight and delete all from "login" to end of line in the URL
8. I press Enter
9. I log in to WordPress
10. It tells me I can click to go back to SO
11. I click and I'm in

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Don't log out in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this "process" is specific to wordpress. I recommend trying Google, Yahoo, or MyOpenID as secondary providers.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/google-offers-named-openids/

Comment: Since my blog is on WordPress, I guess I'll have to try to push them to improve theirs. Meanwhile, back to Google which always has all the answers ...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a second openid from another provider. Using your google profile, for example, isn't as convoluted as the process you describe.